# Insert row in nested Telerik MVC grid

Tags: telerik-grid

Insert new row button doesn't insert new row in nested grid(Ajax Binding) when I hide (Hidden = true) key field.
Is it a bug or I missed something?
Do I need to bind key field for getting it's value in controller method? I see in telerik examples that its' not obligatory...

Answer (score 0):

it works if you move it to after all columns, even after command columns